# Mongodb Aggregate Complex Document with Nested Lookups

Tags: mongodb

I have these collections:

**Sites**

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("5acdb8f65ea63a27c1facf86"),
  TemplateId: ObjectId("sdfsdfs34234234sdf"),
}
```

**Templates**

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("sdfsdfs34234234sdf"),
  Type: "Site",
  Name: "Site 1",
  Sections:[{
     id: ObjectId("8asdf89asd8f9sdf"),
     Header: "Header1",
     FieldItems: [
           {
            FieldId: ObjectId("jsd32423423423"),
            x: 1,
            y: 0
           },
           {
            FieldId: ObjectId("2342sdffafdasdfdfs"),
            x: 1,
            y: 1
           }
          ]
        },
       (...more sections...)
     ]
}
```

**Fields**

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("jsd32423423423"),
  Type: "Phone",
  Name: "Phone_Test"
},
{
  _id: ObjectId("2342sdffafdasdfdfs"),
  Type: "Numeric",
  Name: "Number_Test"
}
```

I'm new to MongoDB, but have taken a couple of days reading through questions and answers as well as documentation.  I'm using MongoDB 4.2.6.  I'm trying to return a result formatted like this:

```
{
  id: ObjectId("5acdb8f65ea63a27c1facf86"),
  TemplateId: ObjectId("sdfsdfs34234234sdf"),
  Template: {
   id: ObjectId("sdfsdfs34234234sdf"),
   Type: "Site",
   Sections:[{
     id: ObjectId("8asdf89asd8f9sdf"),
     Header: "Header1",
     FieldItems: [
        {
          FieldId: ObjectId("jsd32423423423"),
          x: 1,
          y: 0,
          Field: {
              _id: ObjectId("jsd32423423423"),
              Type: "Phone",
              Name: "Phone_Test"
           }
        }, (...)]
      }]
}
```

I've written an aggregate query with nested lookups to get me mostly there, but to get it to work I've had to unwind *Sections* and *FieldItems*.  I haven't figured out a way to get the arrays to the way I'd like them.  I've tried group but having issues with the sub arrays.  I'm not even sure if this is the best way to get the results I need:

```
db.getCollection("AppSites").aggregate(
[
    { 
        "$lookup" : { 
            "from" : "AppTemplates", 
            "let": {"template_id": "$TemplateId"},
            "pipeline": [
                { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq" : ["$_id", "$$template_id"] } } },
                { "$unwind": "$Sections"},
                { "$unwind": "$Sections.FieldItems"},
                {
                    "$lookup": {
                        "from": "AppFields",
                        "let": {"field_id": "$Sections.FieldItems.FieldId"},
                        "pipeline": [
                            { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$_id", "$$field_id"] } } }
                        ],
                        "as": "Sections.FieldItems.Field"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "as" : "Templates"
        }
    }
]
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done `$unwind` two times, So you need you use two `$group`.

```
{
  $group: {
    _id: {
      secId: "$_id",
      fId: "$Sections.id"
    },
    Type: {
      $first: "$Type"
    },
    Name: {
      $first: "$Name"
    },
    Header: {
      $first: "$Sections.Header"
    },
    fieldItems: {
      $push: "$Sections.FieldItems"
    }
  }
},
{
  $group: {
    _id: "$_id.secId",
    Type: {
      $first: "$Type"
    },
    Name: {
      $first: "$Name"
    },
    Sections: {
      $push: {
        id: "$_id.fId",
        Header: "$Header",
        fieldItems: "$fieldItems"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

1. First group - to group child objects. But **Type,Name and Header** need to be set to parent and child array respectively.
2. Second group - to group parent objects. We get every standalone fields while grouping child. Here just we need to set it up in correct oreders.

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RAaOeaS031p)

Note : When you use `$lookup`, it will provide an array. But there are some places you just make it as object. I don't know whether your joins in one-to-one relationship or not. If so you can use [positional operator in projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) or [arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/)