# MongoDB $lookup based on two schema

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to know how to query in mongo db based on two other schema collection.

I have 3 schema's in mongo db:

```
 1. Site : {_id, name}
 2. Components : { _id, siteId, details }
 3. Maintenance : { _id, siteId }
```

I want to query and get all the `components` with `site information` and at same time ensuring that they are not in `maintenance`.

I am able to fetch `components` with `site information` with following query:

```
componentCollection
        .aggregate([
          {
            $lookup: {
              from: 'sites',
              localField: 'siteId',
              foreignField: '_id',
              as: 'sites',
            },
          },
        ])
```

How to update this query so that I can ensure **selected `components` site's** are not in `maintenance` collection?

### Update with sample data, expected and current output:

```
`Site`
---------------------------
_id   | name
---------------------------
1     | site1
---------------------------
2     | site2
---------------------------

`Components`
---------------------------
_id   | siteId  | details
---------------------------
3     | 1       | help & support
---------------------------
4     | 2       | footer links
---------------------------


`Maintenance`
---------------------------
_id   | siteId
---------------------------
5     | 1
---------------------------
```

With the above sample query I am getting the following result:

```
[
 {
   _id: 3,
   siteId: 1,
   details: 'help & support',
   sites: [
     {
       _id: 1,
       name: 'site1'
     }
   ]
 },
 {
   _id: 4,
   siteId: 2,
   details: 'footer links',
   sites: [
     {
       _id: 2,
       name: 'site2'
     }
   ]
 }
]
```

But I want only below, as `site1` is in maintenance mode

```
[
 {
   _id: 4,
   siteId: 2,
   details: 'footer links',
   sites: [
     {
       _id: 2,
       name: 'site2'
     }
   ]
 }
]
```

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63471903/mongodb-aggregate-complex-document-with-nested-lookups/63473631#63473631 help you? This is for nested lookups

Comment: try the above, else please post some sample data and expected output

Comment: Hey thanks for the link, I am not able to understand from the give link how I am supposed to update my query.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question with sample data, with expected and and current output

Comment: Why do you tag it as MySql??

Comment: @nacho Sorry my bad. I thought insight and the idea around to address this kind of situation in MySql will help me to quickly figure out the solution in mongo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you.

1. Join the **Components** Collection and **Site** Collection
2. Nested join the **Site** and **Maintenance**. Because if **Maintenance** has the **Site**, we can easily eliminate the object.
3. Filter out the object in the Site array if **joinMaintenance** is an empty array using `$filter`.
4. So if **joinMaintenance** doesn't have any objects, it will exist in **Sites**

Here is the code

```
[
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "Site",
      "let": {
        "sId": "$siteId"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$_id",
                "$$sId"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "Maintenance",
            let: {
              "smId": "$_id"
            },
            pipeline: [
              {
                "$match": {
                  $expr: {
                    $eq: [
                      "$siteId",
                      "$$smId"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            as: "joinMaintenance"
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "sites"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      details: 1,
      siteId: 1,
      sites: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$sites",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              "$$this.joinMaintenance",
              []
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $ne: [
          "$sites",
          []
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "sites.joinMaintenance": 0
    }
  }
]
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/di9TwtjEO2z)

Comment: +Thank you, I will try this and update the status of this post1.

Comment: Sure. I will try my best to give u the expected output

Comment: I got empty result for this query!!

Comment: Bit this is what yoi gave us, and its working on the demo. Sometimes you may need to check the variable names matching.

Comment: One more query related to this, why in the results I am not getting other details in the `Components` ? I have updated playground structure little bit, can you look into that?  https://mongoplayground.net/p/OeZU1-yP-VL

Comment: bcs we didnt include in projection . working https://mongoplayground.net/p/MwJrOtAJMQV . please refer https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/

Comment: If you have more fields that all you need, replace `$project` with `$addFields`. `$addFields` won't remove any fields, other way around, it will add field where you need

Comment: Thank you so much, I already upvoted for this answer. One more last query around this solution, what if I have to select `components` which are in `maintenance` table?

Comment: I didn't get you. Can you explain briefly ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220116/discussion-between-piccaza-de-and-varman).